# PHPUnit Mockupbuilder passing return value correctly

Tags: php, phpunit

I found some strange behavior with mockup builder, can someone explain to me why this happen?

here is my test code:

```
class PlaceTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    const API_KEY = 'test-api';

    public function testConstruct()
    {
        $google = $this->getMockBuilder('GusDeCooL\GooglePhp\Google')
            ->setConstructorArgs(array(self::API_KEY))
                            ->setMethods(array('getKey'))
            ->getMock();
        $google->expects($this->any())
            ->method('getKey')
            ->will($this->returnValue(self::API_KEY));

        /* @var $google \GusDeCooL\GooglePhp\Google */
        $place = new Place($google);
        $this->assertInstanceOf('GusDeCooL\GooglePhp\Component\Place\Place', $place);
        $this->assertInstanceOf('GusDeCooL\GooglePhp\Google', $place->getParent());
        $this->assertEquals(self::API_KEY, $place->getKey());
        return $place;
    }



    /**
     * @param Place $place
     *
     * @depends testConstruct
     */
    public function testGetKey(Place $place)
    {
        $this->assertInstanceOf('GusDeCooL\GooglePhp\Google', $place->getParent());
        $this->assertEquals(self::API_KEY, $place->getKey());
    }
}
```

And here is the code of actual class

```
<?php



namespace GusDeCooL\GooglePhp\Component\Place;

use GusDeCooL\GooglePhp\Component\ChildInterface;
use GusDeCooL\GooglePhp\Google;
use GusDeCooL\GooglePhp\Place\Nearby;

class Place implements ChildInterface
{
    /**
     * @var Google
     */
    private $parent;

    /**
     * @var Nearby
     */
    private $nearby;

    public function __construct(Google $parent)
    {
        $this->setParent($parent);
    }


    /**
     * API Key
     * @return string
     */
    public function getKey()
    {
        return $this->getParent()->getKey();
    }
}
```

While running the test, the `PlaceTest::testConstruct()` while doing `$place->getKey()` it pass the test but it errors in `PlaceTest::testGetKey()`

How is that happen?

Comment: Your not using setMethods() when you build the mock object so it's overloading everything. Chain `->setMethods(array('getKey'))` before you getMock()

Comment: @MikeB I updating the code like your suggest, but when i tried it. i still get the same error: `PHPUnit_Framework_ExpectationFailedException : Failed asserting that null matches expected 'test-api'.
Expected :test-api
Actual   :null`

Comment: Can you debug $this->getParent() within your Place::getKey() method? If all is well $this->getParent() should be an instance of your mocked Google class. If it's null or Vanilla Google then you're not setting your mocked class properly.

Comment: @MikeB I had debugged `$this->getParent()` it has mocked Google class and also have property `$this->key = test-api`. But when executed `Google:getKey()` it returned null.

Comment: You can't mock static calls. Google::getKey() is always going to miss the mocked class and go straight to the source.

Comment: nope, it not static. I use `Google:getKey()` so i can easily describe which class had it's method. in real code it like `$this->getKey` ($this instanceof Google)

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is the limitation of mockup builder.
http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/test-doubles.html

we can't pass mockup object into another test scope.

Please leave a comment if you found another reason.

[image]